# Magento 2 ui list component issue with enabled FPC

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, full-page-cache

I use **UI list component** to show **custom product listing** on frontend on cms view page.

Here an **example** how I put it to layout:

```
        <container htmlTag="div" name="ui-listing-knockout" htmlClass="listing-ui" after="-">
            <uiComponent name="widget_product_products_list"/>
        </container>
```

But with **enabled FPC** this **ui component** is **broken** randomly, not always

here example: https://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1551114564.png

I can't find the reason why this UI component broken some times with FPC. Did somebody has issue like this?